# cobfusc generates unknown characters

Tags: c, obfuscation

I wanted to get an obfuscated output (for students). I used this example:

#### Input file *hello.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

#### Generate obfuscated file, *olleh.c*

```
cobfusc hello.c -o olleh.c
```

#### Output file *olleh.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

�my�U �my�U() {
    �my�U("Hello, World!\n");
}%
```

#### Compiling *olleh.c*

```
gcc olleh.c
```

#### Output:

```
olleh.c:3:1: error: stray ‘\344’ in program
    3 | �my�U �my�U() {
      | ^
olleh.c:3:2: error: stray ‘\16’ in program
    3 | �my�U �my�U() {
      |  ^
olleh.c:3:5: error: stray ‘\333’ in program
    3 | �my�U �my�U() {
      |     ^
olleh.c:3:3: error: unknown type name ‘my’
    3 | �my�U �my�U() {
```

Is this the expected behaviour? I thought the output should be compilable.

Comment: You're asking what some program is supposed to do, not really a programming question. What do the instructions say? Have you checked their bugtracker?

Comment: Did you check the documentation of "cobfusc" about character encoding?

Comment: @thebusybee Nothing about encoding in here : http://manpages.org/cobfusc

Comment: Yes, I found the man page too brief. Have you searched for a project/web site, or looked into the source to find out what the different modes do?

Comment: "For a more complete documentation, please read the Info file or the Texinfo manual." There's probably some option that restricts the characters   or character set.

Answer (score 0):

The README.compile explains the issue with "flex" and says that you need to either use "lex" or use "flex -l".

The easiest fix is to update all the Makefiles after you run ./configure and update the LEX= line to flex -l, instead of flex.

Happy obfuscating!